# Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined" in Unit Test with Jest

Tags: typescript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-i18n

I wrote a unit test for my Vue.js component but after hours of trying and searching the internet, I still keep getting this error:

> console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1884
> **TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined**
> at Proxy.Vue.$t ([...]\node_modules\vue-i18n\dist\vue-i18n.common.js:194:17)
> at Proxy.render ([...]\src\components\Foo.vue:186:175)
> at [...]

In my `Foo.vue` component I use `$t` like this, which is provided by the `vue-i18n` plugin:

```
<template>
  <b-form-group :label="$t('foo.label')">
    [...]
  </b-form-group>
</template>
```

My `Foo.spec.ts` looks like this:

```
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount, mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Foo from "@/components/Foo.vue";
import { i18n } from "@/i18n";

describe("Foo", () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue() as any;
  localVue.use(i18n);
  
  const wrapper = mount(Foo, { localVue } ) as any;

  describe("removeLabel", () => {  
    it("should remove label", async () => {
      // Arrange
      const index = 1;

      // Act
      wrapper.vm.removeLabel(index);

      // Assert
      expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy();
      // [more expectations... ]
    });
  });
});
```

I checked all other Stack Overflow issue with the same error message, but in none the unit test causes this error.
As per Vue.js docs, I tried to hand a mock into the mount function for _t, but with no success:

```
const $mocks = { $t: () => {} };
const wrapper = mount(Foo, { localVue, mocks: { $mocks } }) as any;
```

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through Github issues discussing that very error, I found [this magic comment](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/323#issuecomment-408178398) by `cesalberca`:

> "This works as long as it's shallow. If you mount the component and any
> subcomponent uses translations the tests will fail [...]"

I replaced `mount` by `shallowMount` and now the error is gone:

```
// const wrapper = mount(Foo, { localVue, mocks: { $t: () => {} } }) as any;

const wrapper = shallowMount(Foo, { localVue, mocks: { $t: () => {} } }) as any;
```